# sql query to delete parent table rows which are not used in child table

Tags: mysql, sql

my question title saying exactly what i want help.

**Table defination & relation:**

[image]

---

I tried this below query but its not delete the data "jl" from measuring_units table. I want to delete that row with 62 in "measuring_units" table, because it is not being used in "food_units_relation" table

this one i tried:

```
DELETE  t2
        FROM food_units_relation t1 JOIN measureing_units t2
        ON t1.measuring_unit_id = t2.measuremnt_id
        WHERE t1.foodUnit_relation_Id = 17 and  t2.measuremnt_id NOT IN(t1.measuring_unit_id) and t2.creater_id=1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE  t2
FROM measureing_units t2
LEFT JOIN food_units_relation t1 ON t1.measuring_unit_id = t2.measuremnt_id
WHERE t1.foodUnit_relation_Id = 17 and t1.measuring_unit_id is null and t2.creater_id = 1;
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain some of the code. If you do explain this (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner actually learns something!

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat, thanks for notifying. There is not much explaining to do unless the OP follows up. It is straight quick answer :)

Comment: @amit_g I tried your query, its not deleted the record as i explain in my question

Comment: @Sundara t1.foodUnit_relation_Id = 17 must be excluding those records. Try after removing that condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE MEASUREING_UNITS.*
FROM MEASUREING_UNITS
  LEFT JOIN FOOD_UNITS_RELATION ON MEASUREING_UNITS.MEASUREMENT_ID = FOOD_UNITS_RELATION.MEASURING_UNIT_ID
WHERE FOOD_UNITS_RELATION.FOOD_UNITS_RELATION_ID IS NULL;
```

Check it out at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a8e7/1).

Comment: Unknown column 'FOOD_UNITS_RELATION.FOOD_UNITS_RELATION_ID' in 'where clause' and also you have not taken those creater_id & t1.foodUnit_relation_Id combination on where clause

Answer (score 0):

The issue here - you use INNER JOIN so you doesn't even select `measuremnt_id` that doesn't exists in `food_units_relation`. Instead use RIGHT JOIN and also exclude conditions IN WHERE for `t1` table :

```
DELETE  t2
        FROM food_units_relation t1 RIGHT JOIN measureing_units t2
        ON t1.measuring_unit_id = t2.measuremnt_id
        WHERE t1.measuring_unit_id IS NULL 
              AND t2.creater_id=1;
```

Or just use NOT EXISTS:

```
   DELETE FROM measureing_units t2 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM food_units_relation t1 
                        WHERE t1.measuring_unit_id = t2.measuremnt_id)
            AND t2.creater_id=1
```